# How to pass local variable value from function to addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript

How to pass local variable value from function to addEventListener function?

Here is code for example(JavaScript),

```
function f(){

   var x = new Audio('Audio URL')
   var divID = document.getElementById('id of a div');

   if(divID){
      divID.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",g);
      divID.addEventListener("animationend",g);
  }
}


function g(){
    //Code that uses variable x value and functions i.e x.pause() or x.play()
}
```

How to pass the variable x value in function f() to function g() in addEventListener?

Comment: the function g is callback function so you can pass data to g from webkitAnimationEnd

Comment: Can I pass var x value to g() from webkitAnimationEnd? if then how?

Comment: you can use .bind to return a new bound function with seeded arguments. not a great solution, but a possibility. g.bind(elm, x)

Comment: The first argument to `addEventListener` should be a quoted string.

Comment: @Barmar thx! edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
function f(){

   var x = new Audio('Audio URL')
   var divID = document.getElementById('id of a div');

   if(divID){
      divID.addEventListener(webkitAnimationEnd, () => g(x));
      divID.addEventListener(animationend, () => g(x));
  }
}


function g(x){
    //Code that uses variable x value and functions i.e x.pause() or x.play()
}
```

Or, if you want ES5 support, `divID.addEventListener(webkitAnimationEnd, function() { g(x); });`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you'll want to do this with a closure:

```
function f(){

   var x = new Audio('Audio URL')
   var divID = document.getElementById('id of a div');

   if(divID){
      divID.addEventListener(webkitAnimationEnd, makeG(x));
      divID.addEventListener(animationend, makeG(x));
  }
}

function makeG(x) {
    return function() {
        //Code that uses variable x value and functions i.e x.pause() or x.play()
    }
}
```